# R: Interpolation of NAs by group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, zoo, linear-interpolation

I would like to perform a linear interpolation in a variable of a data frame which takes into account the: 1) time difference between the two points, 2) the moment when the data was taken and 3) the individual taken for measure the variable.

For example in the next dataframe:

```
 df <- data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3),
            Individuals=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
            Value=c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, 7, 5, NA, 7))
  df
```

I would like to obtain:

```
 result <- data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3),
                Individuals=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                Value=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5.5, 6))
 result
```

I cannot use exclusively the function `na.approx` of the package `zoo` because all observations are not consecutives, some observations belong to one individual and other observations belong to other ones. The reason is because if the second individual would have its first obsrevation with `NA` and I would use exclusively the function `na.approx`, I would be using information from the `individual==1` to interpolate the `NA` of the `individual==2` (e.g the next data frame would have sucherror)

```
  df_2 <- data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3),
                Individuals=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                Value=c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, 7, NA, 5, 7))
  df_2
```

I have tried using the packages `zoo` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
proof <- df %>%
  group_by(Individuals) %>%
  na.approx(df$Value)
```

But I cannot perform `group_by` in a `zoo` object.

Do you know how to interpolate `NA` values in one variable by groups?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on what your desired output would be? In addition, what is the 'Ear_tag' grouping you are trying for. This column doesn't exist in the dataframe you provided?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `data.frame`, rather than `cbind` to create your data. `cbind` returns a matrix, but you need a data frame for `dplyr`. Then use `na.approx` inside `mutate`. I've commented out `group_by`, as you haven't provided the grouping variable in your data, but the approach should work once you've added the grouping variable to the data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3),
            Individuals=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
            Value=c(NA, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, 7, 8, NA, 10))

library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  group_by(Individuals) %>%
  mutate(ValueInterp = na.approx(Value, na.rm=FALSE))
```

> ```
>    time Individuals Value ValueInterp
> 1     1           1    NA          NA
> 2     2           1     2           2
> 3     3           1     3           3
> 4     4           1    NA           4
> 5     5           1     5           5
> 6     6           1    NA           6
> 7     7           1     7           7
> 8     1           2     8           8
> 9     2           2    NA           9
> 10    3           2    10          10
> ```

**Update:** To interpolate multiple columns, we can use `mutate_at`. Here's an example with two value columns. We use `mutate_at` to run `na.approx` on all columns that include `"Value"` in the column name. `list(interp=na.approx)` tells `mutate_at` to generate new column names by running `na.approx` and adding `interp` as a suffix to generate the new column names:

```
df <- data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3),
                 Individuals=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 Value1=c(NA, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, 7, 8, NA, 10),
                 Value2=c(NA, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, 7, 8, NA, 10)*2)

df %>%
  group_by(Individuals) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("Value")), list(interp=na.approx), na.rm=FALSE)
```

> ```
>     time Individuals Value1 Value2 Value1_interp Value2_interp
>    <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
>  1     1           1     NA     NA            NA            NA
>  2     2           1      2      4             2             4
>  3     3           1      3      6             3             6
>  4     4           1     NA     NA             4             8
>  5     5           1      5     10             5            10
>  6     6           1     NA     NA             6            12
>  7     7           1      7     14             7            14
>  8     1           2      8     16             8            16
>  9     2           2     NA     NA             9            18
> 10     3           2     10     20            10            20
> ```

If you don't want to preserve the original, uninterpolated columns, you can do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Individuals) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("Value")), na.approx, na.rm=FALSE)
```

Comment: Great, It works for the example `df`, but it doesn't works when the `NA` is located in the first or last observation as in the example proposed in `df_2`. Is it possible that the code interpolates at least the data for the observations that aren't the first or last observation?

Comment: Just add `na.rm=FALSE` (see updated code). Then leading and trailing `NA` values will be kept in the resulting vector.

Comment: And how can I perform the interpolation for the entire dataset if I have 1 or 2 observations for one individual and those measures are NAs?  
For example in this datafrate:
`df <- data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3),
                 Individuals=c(3,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 Value=c(NA, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, 7, 8, NA, 10))`
I would like to get the interpolation for the rest of data, but when I applied this code R says:`Error in approx(x[!na], y[!na], xout, ...) : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate`.
Is there any way to don't take into account the impossible cases?

Comment: I want to do the same but for multiple columns, how should modify the code?

Answer (score 5):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df1)[, ValueInterp:= na.approx(Value, na.rm=TRUE), by = Individual]
```

Comment: Yes it works in the cases were the `NA` is not located in the first or last obsrevation of one individual, but it doesn't work when the `NA` is the first or last observation. However the worst is that data.table provides a result suppling items (warning message) and performing bad the assignation what is dangerous if you run a big code where you are not able to check all warning messages.

Comment: @Ruben For `df_2`, what is the expected output?

Comment: The output should have the interpolation of all `NAs` except which that are  the first or last observation of one individual.

Comment: @Ruben DId you mean that for `df_2`, you don't need the 8th row?  By using `na.rm=TRUE`, we get all the NA's replaced except first

Comment: And how can I perform the interpolation for the entire dataset if I have 1 or 2 observations for one individual and those measures are NAs? For example in this datafrate: `df <- data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3), Individuals=c(3,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2), Value=c(NA, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, 7, 8, NA, 10))` 
I would like to get the interpolation for the rest of data, but when I applied this code R says:`Error in approx(x[!na], y[!na], xout, ...) : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate`. 
Is there any way to don't take into account the impossible cases? Thanks

Comment: @Ruben What would be the expected output (just to cross-reference)?

Comment: @Ruben Try `setDT(df)[, ValueInterp := if(length(na.omit(Value))<2) na.omit(Value) else na.approx(Value, na.rm=TRUE), Individuals]`

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much. But it interpolates a value for the first observation of the `Individual==3` when it shouldn't do it because it only has one value to do it. 
The output that I expect is one where the cases impossible to interpolate (because there are no previous and next data from the `NA`) mantain the `ValueInterp==NA`. 
With your updated code the first observation of the `Individuals==3` has `ValueInterp==2` and should be `NA`, I think that it is because the code has interpolated the `NA`with one value, the second observation of the `Individuals==3` the`Value==2`

Comment: @Ruben Just like you showed the dataset `df`, please show the expected output to avoid confusion.

Comment: `expected_df <- data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3), 
                 Individuals=c(3,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2), 
                 Value=c(NA, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, 7, 8, NA, 10),
                 ValueInterp=c(NA,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
expected_df`

Comment: @Ruben Try `setDT(df)[, ValueInterp := if(length(na.omit(Value))<2) Value else na.approx(Value, na.rm=TRUE), Individuals]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95231/discussion-between-ruben-and-akrun).