# Increment column based on second column

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider a dataframe like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(name = c("John", "John", "John", "John", "Sam", "Sam", "Sam", "Sam", "Emily", "Emily", "Emily", "Emily", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex"),
                  grade = c(9, NA, NA, 12, 10, NA, NA, NA, 9, 10, 10, 11, NA, 11, 11, NA),
                  year = c(2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, rep(c(2018, 2019, 2019, 2020), 3)))

    name grade year
1   John     9 2007
2   John    NA 2008
3   John    NA 2009
4   John    12 2010
5    Sam    10 2018
6    Sam    NA 2019
7    Sam    NA 2019
8    Sam    NA 2020
9  Emily     9 2018
10 Emily    10 2019
11 Emily    10 2019
12 Emily    11 2020
13  Alex    NA 2018
14  Alex    11 2019
15  Alex    11 2019
16  Alex    NA 2020
```

I'd like to fill in the missing NAs in `grade` based on `year`.  So `Sam` for example is in 10th grade in 2018, and in 2019 he'll be in 11th grade:

```
dat_desired <- data.frame(name = c("John", "John", "John", "John", "Sam", "Sam", "Sam", "Sam", "Emily", "Emily", "Emily", "Emily", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex"),
                  grade = c(9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 11, 12, 9, 10, 10, 11, 10, 11, 11, 12),
                  year = c(2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, rep(c(2018, 2019, 2019, 2020), 3)))

    name grade year
1   John     9 2007
2   John    10 2008
3   John    11 2009
4   John    12 2010
5    Sam    10 2018
6    Sam    11 2019
7    Sam    11 2019
8    Sam    12 2020
9  Emily     9 2018
10 Emily    10 2019
11 Emily    10 2019
12 Emily    11 2020
13  Alex    10 2018
14  Alex    11 2019
15  Alex    11 2019
16  Alex    12 2020
```

How can I do this?  I've tried:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  fill(grade, .direction = "updown")
```

which doesn't work because it doesn't take `year` into account.  Adding a `group_by(year)` doesn't help either, because then no `NA`s are replaced.

Comment: Maybe it's more complicated than you need, but you could think of this as a linear interpolation problem, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33696795/5325862)

Comment: Linear interpolation (as ```mutate(gradeInterp = zoo::na.approx(grade, na.rm=FALSE))  ```) can deal well with ```John``` but can't handle the leading and trailing ```NA```s in ```Alex```, or the 2 ```NA```s in a row, plus trailing ```NA``` in ```Sam```.  Any thoughts on dealing with those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could try:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(
    grade = coalesce(grade, first(grade[!is.na(grade)]) - (first(year[!is.na(grade)]) - year))
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   name [4]
   name  grade  year
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 John      9  2007
 2 John     10  2008
 3 John     11  2009
 4 John     12  2010
 5 Sam      10  2018
 6 Sam      11  2019
 7 Sam      11  2019
 8 Sam      12  2020
 9 Emily     9  2007
10 Emily    10  2008
11 Emily    10  2009
12 Emily    11  2010
13 Alex     10  2018
14 Alex     11  2019
15 Alex     11  2019
16 Alex     12  2020
```

Answer (score 1):

A rough solution can be implemented with a for loop:

```
X <- as.character(unique(dat$name))

for ( i in 1:length(X)){
a <- min(dat[dat$name==X[i],]$grade, na.rm = T)
b <- min(dat[dat$name==X[i],]$year, na.rm = T)
dat[dat$name==X[i] & is.na(dat$grade),]$grade <- dat[dat$name==X[i] & is.na(dat$grade),]$year-b+a
}
```

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  Some of my data has people who where in school for different years.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Oh! So it's a good question! I've edited my response in order to take in account that.

Comment: This does work, so +1 and thanks, but a for loop is tough in my actual application.  ```length(X)``` is ~30,000.